# Google Maps API v3 - How to update the InfoWindow of a Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to target a specific Marker's InfoWindow to update it?

When a Marker is clicked, it opens the InfoWindow showing name and address. It also sends the Lat and Long to a PHP script to bring back more details about this Marker from the database in a div off the map.

I would like to be able to update the name and address using this off-map div, which is no problem - I am stuck on how to target that particular Marker's InfoWindow to update it with the new name and address though.

I've added an id to each Marker, but I'm not sure how to use it (or if it's possible) to target the Marker with that id and update its InfoWindow from my other function that sends the info to the database.

```js
     var map;
     var map_center = {lat: <?=$map['lat']?>, lng: <?=$map['lng']?>};
     var markers = [];
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     map_initialize(); // initialize google map
     
     //############### Google Map Initialize ##############
     function map_initialize() {
        var googleMapOptions = { 
          center: map_center, // map center
          zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
          panControl: true, //enable pan Control
          zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
          zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
         scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };
    
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), googleMapOptions);         
        
        $.getJSON("<?=$urlpath?>map_process.php", function(data) {
         
       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      var point      = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(val['lat']),parseFloat(val['lng']));
      var name       = val['name'];
      var address    = '<p>'+ val['address'] +'</p>';
      var properties = val['properties'];
     var id     = val['id'];
     
     create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, "/images/pin_green.png", properties, id);
      })
   });
                            
    }

  //############### Function create_marker ##############
  
  
  function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, iconPath, properties, id) {           
     
     var this_id = 'marker_' + id;
      
      //new marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       id: this_id,
         position: MapPos,
         map: map,
         draggable: DragAble,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         title: MapTitle,
         icon: iconPath,
         properties: properties
      });
      
      //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
      var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
      '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
      '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
      MapDesc+ 
      '</span>'+
      '</div></div>');    

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {

       infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
       
       //############### Send latlng to right panel ##############
       
       var mLatLang = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
       showRightPanel(mLatLang);
       
     });
          
    markers.push(marker);
   }  




   function showRightPanel(mLatLang) { //function that will add markers on button click
   
       var myData = {latlang : mLatLang}; //post variables
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<?=$urlpath?>map_show_panel.php",
         data: myData,
         success:function(data){
          $('#marker_result').html(data);
         },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
         }
       });
   
   }
```

Comment: If the InfoWindow is already open (added to the DOM), you can use normal javascript/jquery methods for accessing the HTML elements in it.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. I want to be able to update the content associated with the Marker, so if the Marker is clicked later, it will show this updated content rather than the content originally set with var contentString = ....

Comment: I've done a workaround where I update the infoWindow with an ajax call, but this isn't quite what I wanted to happen, it seems like an extra call that's not necessary, I only need to do it when the content needs updating (quite rarely)

Comment: If you want to update the content of the InfoWindow persistently, store it in a member variable of the marker, and use that to create the InfoWindow when the marker is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I cobbled it together by running through the marker array until I found one with matching ID (stored in member variable) and then updating the content into a further member variable, which gets called on click of the marker.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `infoWindow' is your infoWindow object  you can change the content of an infoWindow  if you can access (you have visibility of the infoWindow object) using`setContent()`eg :

```
  infoWindow.setContent('your new content');
```

Comment: this worked for me on Ionic... bigup... thank you very much